# checkbox array in knockout being all checked on click

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am having an issue with knockout,
when i check a box, they're all being checked...

this is what I have:
_Categories_List has all the items, 
and
My_categories is the empty list where I want to have each id added

this is the code:

```
 <!-- ko foreach: _Categories_List --> 
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: {value: $data}, checked: $root.My_categories" />
    <span data-bind="text: CODE"></span><br />
 <!-- /ko -->
```

and this is the JS part of the code (i cant really change this as to how the code is in the documentation because i'm building off someone else's work and should use the same code - referring to the mapping.fromJS):

```
var Poi = new Object();  
Poi.My_categories = [];
var _Poi = ko.mapping.fromJS(Poi);

var Categories_List = [];
var _Categories_List = ko.mapping.fromJS(Categories_List);

$(document).ready
(
    function () {        
       ko.applyBindings(_Poi);
       // here there's an ajax function to load the categories returned in i_Input.My_Result, then:
       ko.mapping.fromJS(i_Input.My_Result, _Categories_List);
    }
);
```

this is what the object loaded from ajax looks like:

```
{"My_Result":[
  {"CODE":"chalet","DEF_POIS_CATEGORY_ID":2,"DESCRIPTION":"chalet","ENTRY_DATE":"2012-10-10","ENTRY_USER_ID":2,"OWNER_ID":1},
  {"CODE":"vila","DEF_POIS_CATEGORY_ID":3,"DESCRIPTION":"villa","ENTRY_DATE":"2012-10-10","ENTRY_USER_ID":2,"OWNER_ID":1}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `checked` binding works off of the `value` of the input element.  In your code, you are setting the value equal to an object, which turns into `[object Object]`, so both of your inputs have the same value, which is why checking one toggles both.

So, you would want to set your value equal to a key on the object like your `CODE` property. If necessary, then you can use a computed observable to represent the actual objects.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7n9gR/

Comment: thanks...that works, but thing is I would like to put all the data inside My_Categories, for for examples if I selected 1 item, I would like my_categories to have all of this:
{"CODE":"chalet","DEF_POIS_CATEGORY_ID":2,"DESCRIPTION":"chalet","ENTRY_DATE":"2012-10-10","ENTRY_USER_ID":2,"OWNER_ID":1}

any ideas?
thanks alot!

Comment: You would likely want to add a computed to represent the actual objects.  Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/vQMRX/

Comment: thank you, seems to be exactly what I need, but I'm now getting the following error: "cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters".

The code flow is as such:
- initialize paramaters with Poi being empty
- read with ajax the values and populate Poi

Comment: Can you fork my fiddle and reproduce?

Comment: yes, i was doing that just now, i press enter by mistake while typing:
I updated the jsfiddle to include the whole code...but on jsfiddle it's not working for some reason... I've been using knockout for 1.5 weeks and it's still a bit confusing; this is the update: http://jsfiddle.net/vQMRX/6/  
many many thanks

Comment: Had a little trouble following the fiddle, but take a look at the changes in this one: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/vQMRX/7/

Comment: sorry, my bad, had forgot to update the html part...
the code i have is basically matching on html and ko part, but i get the above error...the error happens after i call this  ko.mapping.fromJS(poiData.My_Result, _Poi), when i don't call it, everything works smoothly except that the poi data is actually empty...what could it be?

Comment: i figured out what was causing the problem, I updated the code here::
http://jsfiddle.net/uFHAV/

I assumed the translations bit and html wouldn't be related to the problem, but apparently it is , the script stops working because of this (3rd line in code):
<input type="text" data-bind="value: My_Pois_translation()[0].NAME" />

Comment: It looks like translation is defined in poiData, but you never use it in your `Poi` object.

Comment: did this update http://jsfiddle.net/uFHAV/1/  , added the translation to the object (it was there before, but forgot to include it in the code on jsfiddle)...it still doesn't work....what do you think might be causing it to crash?